# Issue in generating all permutations of columns in a dataframe in Ipython

Tags: python, algorithm, dataframe, permutation, combinatorics

I am working in `Ipython` and trying to generate all the permutations of the columns present in the `dataframe`. This issue is that I have about 15 columns in my `dataframe` and the code just doesn't reach end and keeps on executing. Here is my current code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ';', error_bad_lines=False)

def all_perms(str):
    if len(str) <=1:
        yield str
    else:
        for perm in all_perms(str[1:]):
            for i in range(len(str)):
                #nb str[0:1] works in both string and list contexts
                yield perm[:i] + str[0:1] + perm[i:]

allperms_list = []
for p in all_perms(df.columns[:len(df.columns)]):
    allperms_list.append(p)
```

I followed [this SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python). I have a 16 core and 32GB memory system and have been running this code for last 1.5 hours but its still executing and doesn't look like reaching an end. Is there some fundamental issue in the code that I have? How can I make this to run faster without affecting final result? I read that `itertools.permutations` is another option. How can I modify my current code to include `itertools.permutations` and achieve the same result?

Comment: `from itertools import permutations;for p in permutations(df.columns)):print p`,  how many columns do you have?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have 15 columns in my dataframe

Comment: That should not be running for 1.5 hours

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes thats why I thought there is something wrong that I am doing in my code

Comment: @PadraicCunningham is there anything wrong that you can se in my code above? And is using `itertools.permutations` better that the above approach in terms in speed (in terms of complexity it definitely looks better to have a two line code in itertools.permutations than my approach)?

Comment: itertools is implemented in c so it is optimized in that sense, there are still n! possible permutations however you approach it. I cannot see any reason in your code, have you added some prints in the loop to see what is happening?